# Active Menu Highlight CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to highlight the current menu you have click. I'm using CSS, but it is now working.

here is my css code:

```
#sub-header ul li:hover{ background-color: #000;}
#sub-header ul li:hover a{ color: #fff; }
#sub-header ul li.active{ background-color: #000; }
#sub-header ul li.active a{ color: #fff; }
```

here is my html:

```
<div id="sub-header">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="about.php">About Us</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I like when I hover and if the menu is active

[image: This is what I like when I hover and if the menu is active]

Hover is okay, The problem is when I after click the menu the black ground is not display

---

@Jonathan, I have already solve it and it is more simply than what you have gave.

this is my answer:

```
$(function(){
    // this will get the full URL at the address bar
    var url = window.location.href; 

    // passes on every "a" tag 
    $("#sub-header a").each(function() {
            // checks if its the same on the address bar
        if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

then on my css file:

```
.active { background-color: #000; }
/* to override the existing css for "a" tag */
#sub-header .active a{ color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add a class to the body of each page:

```
<body class="home">
```

Or if you're on the contact page:

```
<body class="contact">
```

Then take this into consideration when you're creating your styles:

```
#sub-header ul li:hover,
body.home li.home,
body.contact li.contact { background-color: #000;}

#sub-header ul li:hover a,
body.home li.home a,
body.contact li.contact a { color: #fff; }
```

Lastly, apply class names to your list items:

```
<ul>
  <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li class="about"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

This point, whenever you're on the `body.home` page, your `li.home a` link will have default styling indicating it is the current page.

Comment: @justin Check your selectors. It's a fairly straight-forward solution to implement. `body.foo li.foo { background: bar }`.

Comment: sorry, now it is working... but is there another why to achieve it? by not adding class or id.

Comment: @justin If you're leaving the page, then no. I mean, you could use some clever JavaScript to sniff the current URL and find the corresponding `<a>` element, and add a special class to it.

Comment: do you have example of using javascript ?

Comment: @justin The JavaScript would be somewhat verbose, however a jQuery solution could be done in just a couple of lines I'm sure.

Comment: @justin Here's a question that appears to be addressing that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955851/highlight-current-page-in-jquery

Comment: I have solved it already. I place the code below my question above. thanks for the help.

Comment: @justin Just keep in mind that the jQuery solution only works as long as the user has JavaScript enabled.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution is only practical if you don't have many pages in your navigation menu. If for example you have a registry with hundreds of pages, this would quickly get messy.

Comment: is it possible to put the class in a `<div>` instead in a `<body>` tag?

Comment: It would be better to use an `aria-page=current` attribute instead of a class. This because CSS classes cannot tell browsers what page is active. This solution benefits people using assistive tech, for example people with low vision using screen readers. A lot of folks learn to code via Stack Overflow, if we use best practices in these examples the web will become more accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: You need CSS for “current” link here is tut.

[Description of jQuery menu nav](http://www.kevinleary.net/highlighting-the-current-page-with-php-jquery/)

Sample : [One of meny solution](http://www.kevinleary.net/wp-samples/jquery-current-navigation/index.html)

Its working for me

Comment: Link-only answers aren't considered valuable on SO. Please provide the solution _here_.

Answer (score 2):

add simply way

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class=''><a href='1.html'><span>1</span></a></li>
<li class=''><a href='2.html'><span>2</span></a></li>
<li class='' style="float:right;"><a href='3.html'><span>3</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

$("document").ready(function(){
$(function() {
$('.cssmenu a[href="' + location.pathname.split("/")[location.pathname.split("/").length-1] + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

As the given tag to this question is *CSS*, I will provide the way I accomplished it.

1. Create a class in the .css file.

   `a.activePage{ color: green; border-bottom: solid; border-width: 3px;}`
2. Nav-bar will be like:

   - Home
   - Contact Us
   - About Us

**NOTE:** If you are already setting the style for all Nav-Bar elements using a class, you can cascade the special-case class we created with a *white-space* after the generic class in the html-tag.
*Example:* Here, I was already importing my style from a class called *'navList'* I created for all list-items . But the special-case styling-attributes are part of class *'activePage'*

.CSS file:

```
a.navList{text-decoration: none; color: gray;}
a.activePage{ color: green; border-bottom: solid; border-width: 3px;}
```

.HTML file:

```
<div id="sub-header">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.php" class= "navList activePage" >Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="contact.php" class= "navList">Contact Us</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="about.php" class= "navList">About Us</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Look how I've cascaded one class-name behind other.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is very very bad way and just for lazy person 
but I decided to say it.

I used PHP and bootstrap and fontawsome too

for simple I have 2 pages: 1.index and 2.create-user

put this code above your code

```
<?php
$name=basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$name=str_replace(".php","",$name);
switch ($name) {
    case "create-user":
        $a = 2;
        break;
    case "index":
        $a = 1;
        break;
    default:
        $a=1;
}
?>
```

and 
in menu you add `<?php if($a==1){echo "active";} ?>` in class for menu1
and for menu2 you add `<?php if($a==2){echo "active";} ?>`

```
<ul id="menu" class="navbar-nav  flex-column text-right mt-3 p-1">
                        <li class="nav-item mb-2">
                            <a href="index.php" class="nav-link text-white customlihamid <?php if($a==1){echo "active";} ?>"><i
                                        class="fas fa-home fa-lg text-light ml-3"></i>dashbord</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item mb-2">
                            <a href="#" href="javascript:" data-parent="#menu" data-toggle="collapse"
                               class="accordion-toggle nav-link text-white customlihamid <?php if($a==2){echo "active";} ?>" data-target="#tickets">
                                <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg text-light ml-3"></i>manage users
                                <span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled mt-2 mr-1 pr-2" id="tickets">
                                <li class="nav-item mb-2">
                                    <a href="create-user.php" class="nav-link text-white customlihamid"><i class="fas fa-user-plus fa-lg text-light ml-3"></i>add user</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="nav-item mb-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white customlihamid"><i class="fas fa-user-times fa-lg text-light ml-3"></i>delete user</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
```

and add in css

```
.customlihamid {
    transition: all .4s;
}

.customlihamid:hover {
    background-color: #8a8a8a;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #00cc99;
}
.nav-item > .nav-link.active  {
    background-color: #00cc99;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 5px 7px 10px #111;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.nav-item > .nav-link.active:hover  {
    background-color: #8eccc1;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 5px 7px 20px #111;
    transform: translateY(-1px);
}
```

and in js add

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.navbar-nav .nav-link').click(function(){
      $('.navbar-nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   })
});
```

first check your work without js code to understand js code for what

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a menu like this:

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="link1.html">Link 1</a>
  <a href="link2.html">Link 2</a>
  <a href="link3.html">Link 3</a>
  <a href="link4.html">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Let our current url be `https://demosite.com/link1.html`

With the following function we can add the active class to which menu's href is in our url.

```
let currentURL = window.location.href;

document.querySelectorAll(".menu a").forEach(p => {
  if(currentURL.indexOf(p.getAttribute("href")) !== -1){
    p.classList.add("active");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, give all your links a unique id and make a css class called active:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="link1" href="#/...">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link2" href="#/...">link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.active {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Jquery version:**

```
function setActiveLink(setActive){
    if ($("a").hasClass('active'))
        $("a").removeClass('active');
    if (setActive)
        $("#"+setActive).addClass('active');
}

$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        setActiveLink(this.id);
    });
});
```

**Vanilla javascript version:**

In order to prevent selecting too many links with `document.querySelectorAll`, give the parent element an id called menuLinks. Add an onClick handler on the links.

```
<ul id="menuLinks">
    <li><a id="link1" href="#/..." onClick="setActiveLink(this.id);">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link2" href="#/..." onClick="setActiveLink(this.id);">link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Code:

```
function setActiveLink(setActive){
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("#menuLinks a");
    Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        e.className = "";
        if (e.id == setActive)
            e.className = "active";
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the current element and not all elements matching your selector.

```
$("#mainMenu td").click(function() {
$(this).css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
```

});

I´d also recommend you to use CSS classes instead of setting the CSS properties this way.

That would be something like;

```
$("#mainMenu td").click(function() {
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

});

together with;

```
#mainMenu td.selected {
```

background-color: #EDEDED;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Do copy and paste):

Test.html:-

```
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <a class="fruit" href="#">Home</a></span>
 <a class="fruit"  href="#">About</a></span>
 <a class="fruit"  href="#">Contact</a></span>
</html>
```

style.css:-

```
a:link{
 color:blue;
}

a:visited{
 color:purple;
}

a:hover{
 color:orange;
}
a:focus{
color:green;
}

a:active{
 color:red;
}

a:active{
 color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation with a simple 2-line listener

```
$( ".menu_button" ).click(function() {

    $( ".menu_button" ).removeClass('menu_button_highlight');
    $(this).addClass('menu_button_highlight');
});
```

=====

```
    <a class='menu_button' href='#admin'>Admin</a>
    <br/>

    <a class='menu_button' href='#user_manager'>User Manager</a>
    <br/>

    <a class='menu_button' href='#invite_codes'>Invite Codes</a>
```

====

```
.menu_button {

    padding: 0 5px;
}

.menu_button_highlight {

    background: #ffe94c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @Sampson's answer, I approached it this way -

**HTML:**

1. I have a `div` with `content` class in each page, which holds the **contents** of that page. Header and Footer are separated.
2. I have added a unique class for each page with `content`. For example, if I am creating a **CONTACT US** page, I will put the contents of the page inside `<section class="content contact-us"></section>`.
3. By this, it makes it easier for me to write page specific CSS in a single **style.css**.

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="nav-menu">
            <ul class="parent-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="content contact-us">
        Content for contact us page goes here
    </section>

    <footer> ... </footer>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

1. I have defined a single `active` class, which holds the styling for an active menu.

```css
.active {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="nav-menu">
            <ul class="parent-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="content contact-us">
        Content for contact us page goes here
    </section>

    <footer> ... </footer>

</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

1. Now in JavaScript, I aim to compare the menu link text with the unique class name defined in HTML. I am using jQuery.
2. First I have taken all the menu texts, and performed some string functions to make the texts lowercase and replace spaces with hyphens so it matches the class name.
3. Now, if the `content` class have the same class as menu text (lowercase and without spaces), add `active` class to the menu item.

```js
var $allMenu = $('.nav-menu > .parent-nav > li > a');
var $currentContent = $('.content');
$allMenu.each(function() {
  $singleMenuTitle = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  if ($currentContent.hasClass($singleMenuTitle)) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-menu">
      <ul class="parent-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="content contact-us">
    Content for contact us page goes here
  </section>

  <footer> ... </footer>

</body>
```

**Why I Approached This?**

1. @Sampson's answer worked very well for me, but I noticed that I had to add new code every time I want to add new page.
2. Also in my project, the `body` tag is in `header.php` file which means I cannot write unique class name for every page.