# highlighting default page current menu on a navigation bar

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navbar

I do not succeed in highlighting my default web page, that is e.g: www.mydomain.com.
When it's redirected to index.php and other menu links it's fine, when it's plain domain with no other files I CAn't.
I wrote following Jquery just to enlarge the font size of the link and bring it to  a white color:

```
$(function () {
            var path = window.location.href;
            path = decodeURIComponent(path);
            path =path.substr(path.lastIndexOf("/") +1);

            $('#menu a').each(function () { 
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                href=href.substr(href.lastIndexOf("/") +1);
                if (href.indexOf(path) != -1 && path != "") {
                    $(this).closest('li').find('a').css({'color': 'white' , 'font-size' : '18px' });
                        }
               }); //end of each function
            });
```

HTML markup is:

```
  <div id="menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="$doc_root/index.php" title="Home Page">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="$doc_root/travel/grid.php" title="My Trips">travelling</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">words</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

How can I change my first link menu "Home" to be new font and color when only the domain name is written (www.mydomain.com) ?
I want it to be highlighted as like as index.php is selected. 
Thks a lot.
M
P.S. no matter about redirecting the domain name directly to index.php (I generally know how to do it, I don't know how to do it with Aruba) and I'm looking for a nice "programming" solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each page, set a variable in PHP with that pages name, so for index.php, set a variable with a value 'home'. Do this for each individual menu item. Then on each page load check this variable name and add a class to the relevant menu item. Something like this:

```
 <?php
$menuItems = array(
    'Home' => array('text' => 'Home', 'url' => '/'),
    'Page1' => array('text' => 'Page 1','url' => '/page-1'),
    'Page2' => array('text' => 'Page 2', 'url' => '/page-2'),
    'Page3' => array('text' => 'Page 3', 'url' => '/page-3'),
    'Page4' => array('text' => 'Page 4', 'url' => '/page-4'),
);
?>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <?php
    $miCounter = 1;
    foreach($menuItems as $key => $value):
        $currentLink = '';
            if($pageName === $key):
                $currentLink = 'class="selected"';
            endif;
        ?>
        <li>
            <a <?php echo $currentLink; ?> href="<?php echo $value['url']; ?>">
                <?php echo $value['text']; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So when your current page is 'Home' (`$pageName`) it will add `class="selected"` to the menu link. Then in your css create whatever background or color styles you need for the `selected` class.

Comment: ok Adrian, granted that I believe you're wrong with $value['class'], or at least I think so, my problem is not solved.

Comment: Thks Adrian, do you know a way to be redirected from domain to domain/index.php with some php code? I mean, I can't edit Apache server files cause my site is hosted on some service provider which not allows me to edit such configurations. Thks M. P.S. i believe you are wrong with $value['class']

Comment: Do you mean that when you go to www.domain.com (example) it does not automatically call www.domain.com/index.php

Comment: exactly. if I digit www.domain.com it displays me the same content of index.php but the URL is not redirected to index.php.

Comment: It is calling index.php, this is the server's default call if you do not explicitly set the url to `index.php`. I don't see why you would need to anyway. If you really need to, all you can really do is set all internal link `hrefs` to `"/index.php"` instead of `"/"`, but it makes no difference. `index.php` is being called anyway. Oh, and you were right about the `$value['class']`. I used some code already written and when cleaning it up, I forgot to remove that bit. Good spot!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should be able to change your `Home` link to be just `/`, as `index.php` is [usually] the default document index name and can be omitted.

Also, considering your example, I think it would be more convenient to use `window.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`.

```
#menu a.curpage {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

$('#menu a').each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location.pathname) {
        $(this).addClass('curpage');
    }
});
```

If the menu is as short as five items in the given example, you could simply avoid using JS at all, see the answer in this topic: [Active Menu Highlight CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css#10646813)

Comment: Ok, good as substitution of previous longer JS, still I can't solve my domain problem. When it's www.example.com I can't make it have the same style then www.example.com/index.php. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bumping an old topic, but I have just had the same issue and I found a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu [href]").each(function() {
        if (this.href == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass("active"); <-- INSERT NAME OF YOUR CLASS
        }
        if(window.location.href == "http://YOUR-DOMAIN.??/") {
            $(window.location.href = "http://YOUR-DOMAIN.??/index.php");
            $(this).addClass("active"); <-- INSERT NAME OF YOUR CLASS
        }
    });
});
```

It will redirect from http://your-domain.com/ to http://your-domain.com/index.php and set the "active-class".