# Highlight active menu item using jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I am having troubles highlighting my active menu items. 
I am using CSS for hover but what I understand from other posts is that a:active doesn't work with CSS?

This is what I have so done so far:

HTML

```
 <section id="nav">    
        <li><a class="nav" href="editorial.html">EDITORIAL</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="places.html">PLACES</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="people.html">PEOPLE</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="architecture.html">ARCHITECTURE</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="published.html">PUBLISHED</a></li>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#nav{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
min-width:1300px;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#fff;
list-style:none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#nav li{
display:inline;
}

#nav .nav{
display:inline-block;
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
letter-spacing:1px;
font-size:16pt;
line-height:18pt;
font-weight:400;
text-decoration:none;
margin-right: 3px;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-top:35px;
padding:0px 3px 2px 3px;
}

#nav .nav:hover{
background:#FFFF00;
color:#000;
}

.active{
background:#FFFF00;
color:#000;
}
```

JQUERY

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#nav li .nav").click(function ( e ) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#nav li a.active").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class  
$(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab  

// $(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active content  
});
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "`:active` doesn't work with CSS"? It definitely does "work," but perhaps not in the way you are expecting: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/

Comment: What sort of trouble?  I created a fiddle from your posted code and hovering over the items highlights them.  http://jsfiddle.net/slippery_pete/8495h3L3/

Comment: @SlipperyPete The hover is not what is giving me trouble, I'd like the background to remain yellow when the link is active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() { 
    $('#nav').on('click','.nav', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('#nav').find('.active').removeClass('active').end().end().addClass('active');
        $(activeTab).show();
    });
});
```

I updated the code to use only one click event on the parent container and in the function reduced the DOM traversals.  BUT, you also need to update your CSS.  You aren't getting the background color because of specificity.  You specified the background color and the hover using the `#nav` id.  So you need to specify the .active class that way as well.

```
#nav .active { 
    /* css here */
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! My active link remains highlighted now.

Comment: If I may address a new problem that's come from this, now the menu items don't work. When I click on a menu item it remains highlighted but does not direct me to the next page. Any ideas?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` stops the default action of the link preventing it from actually going anywhere. If you reload the page you will need to pass around which tab to highlight.  The other options is to use AJAX to load the page.

Comment: If you have to reload the page, you should consider using css to highlight the current nav item instead of javascript.  Check out this link for more information:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css

Comment: Use without `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 13):

I used following code. Late answer, but I hope this will help someone.

```
// This will work for both relative and absolute hrefs
function active_menu() {   
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: it helped me because if I added `e.preventDefault();` it stopped the link from working. It also means that the page is selected when you go to it, not just when you click on it. Thank you

Comment: What I did is I kept the code outside of a click handler so that the code just fires no matter what page you are on without depending on a click event to run. So instead of a click on a navbar link and visiting a new page (destroying the effect), the code simply runs on page load giving the desired nav element highlighting. TLDR: Don't make the nav element highlighting dependent on a click to a link, add it to your app.js so it can fire after any page loads.

Comment: do you know how to make the samething for sub nav-items ?

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem. I solve this as.

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
      var url = window.location.href;
      $('nav li').find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $('nav li a').filter(function(){
          return this.href == url;
      }).parent().addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

You can save [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/bvz8rhqt/) demo to local and you can test.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#nav li .nav").click(function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nav li a.active").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class  
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab  
        $(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active content  
    });
});
```

you missed some `#` and also no need to use `$("a", this)` `$(this)` will do the job!

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this only prevents my entire menu from working.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by simply traversing my Menu Urls and matching them with the active page Url then added the active css class to the found result. This worked for me:

```
       //Get the current page link
       current_page_link = document.location.href;

       //Search your menu for a linkURL that is similar to the active pageURL
       $(".navbar-nav a").each(function(){
           var link_loop = $(this).attr("href");
           if(link_loop === current_page_link){
               var found_url = $(this).attr("href");
               $('.navbar-nav a[href="'+found_url+'"]').addClass('active');
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take `text` from `#page-indicator` and set class `active` to `<li><a href="#">text</a></li>`.

```
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 part of navigation -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fifth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sixth</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Page name indicator -->
<span id="page-indicator" class="hidden"><?= $pageName = 'Third' ?></span>

<!-- jQuery 1.11.3 -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.navbar-nav li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == $('#page-indicator').text()) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var url = document.location.href;

      $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
      $('.navbar-nav li a').filter(function(){ 
          return this.href == url;
      }).parent().addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

Try this. It worked well.