# Highlighting active menu link with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS to highlight the link on the menu that corresponds to the page the visitor is currently on, so that they know where they are in the website.

I've used this as a guide [Active Menu Highlight CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css)
but it's still not working.

Can anybody spot where I went wrong?
Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">    
    <li class="editorial"><a class="nav" href="editorial.html">EDITORIAL</a></li>
    <li class="places"><a class="nav" href="places.html">PLACES</a></li>
    <li class="people"><a class="nav" href="people.html">PEOPLE</a></li>
    <li class="architecture"><a class="nav" href="architecture.html">ARCHITECTURE</a></li>
    <li class="projects"><a class="nav" href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li class="published"><a class="nav" href="published.html">PUBLISHED</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've also added a

```
<body class="editorial">
<body class="places">
```

... etc to every page.

CSS

```
#nav .nav:hover,
body.editorial li.editorial,
body.places li.places
body.people li.people 
body.architecture li.architecture
body.projects li.projects
body.published li.published { 
    background:#FFFF00;
    color:#000;
}

#nav .nav:hover a.nav,
body.editorial li.editorial a.nav,
body.places li.places a.nav
body.people li.people a.nav
body.architecture li.architecture a.nav
body.projects li.projects a.nav
body.published li.published a.nav{ 
    background:#FFFF00;
    color:#000; 
}
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css?lq=1

Comment: what is the normal color for the links? is the problem the color or the background color? Also, I'm going to just assume that you included commas between the selectors in your actual css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because your forgot to place commas to separate your selectors:

```
#nav .nav:hover a.nav,
body.editorial li.editorial a.nav,
body.places li.places a.nav,               /* <== forgotten comma */
body.people li.people a.nav,               /* <== forgotten comma */
body.architecture li.architecture a.nav,   /* <== forgotten comma */
body.projects li.projects a.nav,           /* <== forgotten comma */
body.published li.published a.nav { 
  background:#FFFF00;
  color:#000;
}
```

Check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/0rq291ds/