# How can I style a link based on my current page?

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation bar on top of the screen. If I'm on a specific page, let's say "Contact", I want the word be highlighted. If I switch to "Home", the word "Home" is highlighted, and so on. I am only allowed to use CSS and HTML.

```css
body {
    background: black;
}

nav {
    padding:0;
    right:1vw;
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0vh;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    width:98%;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

nav li {
    top:2vh;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:2vw;
    margin-right:2vw;
    margin-bottom:2vh;
    margin-top:2vh;
}

nav li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(71, 80, 23, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    text-align:center;
}

nav:hover li a {
}

nav li a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #cc9900;
    color: #ffff99;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/dedump.html">De dump</a></li>
    <li><a href="/opdrachten.html">Opdrachten</a></li>
    <li><a href="/groepsopdracht.html">Groepsopdracht</a></li>
    <li><a href="/overmij.html">Over mij</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
```

Comment: if each page has this nav menu, why not just color the corresponding nav item on each page...

Comment: what do you mean? Sorry, i'm kinda new:P

Comment: well if your website is plain html/css, then it means that you most likely have this same nav menu on each page, so just make the corresponding nav menu highlighted by default on each page... on home page make the home nav highlighted, and so on...

Comment: hmm okayy, can u explain me what I have to change in the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css Here is the best answer by Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Use following code . 
Change it accordingly

```
a:link, a:visited {
     display: block;
     width: 175px;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     background-color: #00BFFF;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 4px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
  }

a:hover, a:active {
     background-color: #0066FF;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class for the `<li>`, say for eg `<li class="active"><a href="/index.html" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></li>` if you are in the home page.

Similarly, if you are in De Dump page, then the `<li>` should be like

```
<li class="active"><a href="/dedump.html" style="text-decoration:none">De dump</a></li>
```

After you do this, you can just style the class in `CSS` like

```
.active{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply style the relevant list item on each of your pages, for example on the page "Opdrachten" just style the corresponding list item by default:

```css
nav li:nth-child(3) a{
    background:yellow;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px red;
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <li><a href="/index.html" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/dedump.html" style="text-decoration:none">De dump</a></li>
    <li><a href="/opdrachten.html" style="text-decoration:none">Opdrachten</a></li>
    <li><a href="/groepsopdracht.html" style="text-decoration:none">Groepsopdracht</a></li>
    <li><a href="/overmij.html" style="text-decoration:none">Over mij</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
nav ul li {
    background-color: #000000;
}

#page1 ul li.page1 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#page2 ul li.page2 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#page3 ul li.page3 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Page 1 HTML

```
<nav id="page1">
    <ul>
         <li class="page1"><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
         <li class="page2"><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
         <li class="page3"><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Page 2 HTML

```
<nav id="page2">
    <ul>
        <li class="page1"><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
        <li class="page2"><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="page3"><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Change nav id to = page3 for page 3