# Want hover on only one element to change text color

Tags: html, css

If you see the attached [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Renison/sLk0jf4L/105/) and if you hover over the dashboard , it turns black. I want the text "Dashboard" to turn black on just the hover of the `<ul>` and not the `<p>` tag. Is this possible? And can I make it stay active so that the user knows he is on the current page?

```
<div>
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name"></li>
    </ul> <a href="#">
        <ul class="left">
            <li style="margin:10px;"><p style="color:white;">Dashboard</p></li>
        </ul>
    </a>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `.top-bar ul:hover` to `.top-bar ul:hover p`, give it a padding, and you should be good to go

EDIT: Here are the changes:

Your code:

```
  .top-bar {
            height: 55px;
            background: #454545 !important;
        }
        .top-bar ul {
            -o-transition: .5s;
            -moz-transition: .5s;
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
            transition: .5s;
        }
        .top-bar ul:hover,  .top-bar ul li p:hover, .top-bar:last-child {
            background: #C3C3C3;
            color: black !important;

        }
        .top-bar ul li p:hover {
            color: black !important;
        }
```

The edited code:

```
  .top-bar {
            height: 55px;
            background: #454545 !important;
        }
        .top-bar ul {
            -o-transition: .5s;
            -moz-transition: .5s;
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
            transition: .5s;
        }
        .top-bar ul p {
            padding:5px; /* Added padding to make it look more like a button */
        }
        .top-bar ul:hover p, .top-bar:last-child { /* changed .top-bar ul:hover to .top-bar ul:hover p and removed .top-bar ul li p:hover */
            background: #C3C3C3;
            color: black !important;

        }
        .top-bar ul li p:hover {
            color: black !important;
        }
```

Comment: Can you fork my fiddle and show me please? Also I want it to be active as per the current page

Comment: I've added the edited fiddle in my answer, you can see the changes I made there @Rex

Comment: @Rex if this resolved your problem please consider marking my answer as "the answer" by clicking the green check next to, this helps people with the same problem quickly finding the answer.

Comment: it does serve its purpose but the transitions aren't working and is there a way i can set the link to active?

Comment: @Rex You'll have to check which li you clicked the active class, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css) to see one of the many methods to do this