# How can I open a link to another HTML activating a specific div on this new page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating an e-commerce front end page, and I have some questions...
When I click in the login area (inside index.html), I have Login and Create an Account like that: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8pfr.png).

I would like to know if there is a way that when I click in "Login" it opens another HTML file WITH the login form ACTIVATED, and then... I just display none the Create an Account form.
And if I click on the Create an Account button it opens the same HTML file but with the Create an Account form activated and Login form displayed none.
I would like to display both forms on the same HTML file like that:  (THIS IS MY form.html) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H55aY.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwIiA.png)

PS: I'm using Vanilla Javascript, but I can try with jQuery...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active Menu Highlight CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css)

Comment: you can pass in a header variable. websiteName.com/account?login=true; then get the value in javascript. and if login is true say style.display("login") = "block". if its false get the create account page and say style.display("createAccount") = "block". when you toggle between each on the page after it as loaded the url variable wont matter. all you would have to do is toggle using the button clicks.

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help me... I don't know if I will have to do it with AJAX...