# last li menu to stay active

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I keep the sessions li active when the user is not on "About" or "Index" page?

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
<li>
     <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
     <a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">About Me</a>
</li>
<li>
     <a href="@Url.Action("Sessions", "Home")">Schedule A Healing Session</a>
</li>
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        var url = window.location.href;
        var FileName = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        $('nav li').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav li a').filter(function () {
            return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active');

        if (FileName != "Index" && FileName != "About")
        {
            //Here I want to keep "Sessions" active if the user did not select Index or About 
        }

    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active Menu Highlight CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css)

Comment: There are a tonne of tutorials on this, and you don't need JavaScript to do it, either.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href;
var FileName = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

$('nav li').find('.active').removeClass('active');
$('nav li a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');

if (FileName == "Info" || FileName == "Schedule" || FileName === "Confirm") {
    $("#sub-header a").each(function () {
        $(this).closest("li.temp").addClass("active");
    });
}
```

Comment: the above code is my answer to my own question