# highlight the page I am currently in jQuery which is dynamically updated

Tags: php, jquery

I want the link to be highlighted when i am on the current link how can i do this

**Index.php**

```
<a class="menu_top" href="help_files/how_to_reg.php">How to Register</a> 
<a class="menu_top" href="help_files/how_to_reset_pass.php">How to Reset Password</a>   
<a class="menu_top" href="help_files/how_to_up_pix.php">How to Upload Picture</a>
```

**jq.js**

```
$('.menu_top').click(function(){

    var href =$(this).attr('href');
    $('#content_area').fadeOut().load(href).fadeIn('normal');

    return false; // this code prevents us from redirecting to the page 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight current page in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955851/highlight-current-page-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be loading the content dynamically without reloads, so just add a class to the active anchor

```
$('.menu_top').click(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content_area').fadeOut().load(href).fadeIn('normal');

    $('.menu_top').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    return false;
});
```

and style that class however you choose

```
.active { 
    font-weight : bold;
    color : red;
}
```

Comment: This did the Trick Thanks alot