# How to keep selected a list item

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to put a color to the selected list item that has a link?

My code:

```css
.grid a:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<li class="grid">
  <a href="modulo_ordine1.php">Modulo d'ordine</a>
</li>
```

The yellow color stays while in hover.

I want the color yellow to remain in the list item all the time after the list item is visited so if it is selected until another list item is selected. So if I have some list items I want the one which is selected to be colored in yellow until another one is selected.

Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to open the link and if the link is open in any tab the `li.a` should have an other color?

Comment: And when a <li> is selected?

Comment: @Daniel do you need page refresh while clicking on `<a>`?

Comment: If you want to keep the 'active' (or current) menu item highlighted after you've gone to the page, you may want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955851/highlight-current-page-in-jquery This has a jQuery answer to this issue, which essentially scans to see which link links to the page you're on, and applies a class, which you can then style to your liking.

Comment: Selected how and under what circumstances?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery('.grid a').click(function(){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  What does this do differently? Why should it work?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function a(yellow){
  if(yellow=="link1"){
document.getElementById("test").style.background="yellow"
document.getElementById("test1").style.background="none"
    
  }
  else if(yellow=="link2"){
document.getElementById("test").style.background="none"
document.getElementById("test1").style.background="yellow"
    
  }
}
```

```css
 #test{
 background:yellow; 
  
}
```

```html
  <li class="grid">
  <a id="test"  href="#"  onclick="a('link1')">Modulo d'ordine</a>
  
    <a id="test1"  href="#" onclick="a('link2')">Modulo d'ordine1</a>

     </li>
```

Comment: Ok this I like but why doesn't it stays yellow? It stays jusht one second.I want it to remain yellow until another item is clicked.

Comment: it remains yellow on click , what do you want exactly

Comment: To remain yellow all the time when user is on this page not just on click. Then when he clicks to another item this gets deselected and the other item which is clicked remains yellow.

Comment: don't use 'text-speak' on SO.  Write it out.

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  What does this do differently? Why should it work?

Comment: But please why this doesnt stay yellow but is yellow just in click? I want to remain yellow after it is visited and not to be yellow just one second on click.